# Why isn't my mouseover layer showing up on other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layer

I've been trying to create a script to show/hide layers with a mouseover. It works for IE but not for Opera or Chrome.

Here is the code:
`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showFrontLayer() {
            document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='visible';
            document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='visible';
        }
        function hideFrontLayer() {
            document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='hidden';
            document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='hidden';
        }       
    </script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function openWin(url) {
        window.open(url);

    }
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "info.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) { parseXml(xml); }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{

    $(xml).find("media").each(function()
    {
            $("#output").append($(this).find("title").first().text() + "<br />");
            $("#output").append($(this).find("description").text() + "<br />");
        $("#output").append($(this).find("keywords").text() + "<br />");
    });



    $(xml).find("customDataElement").each(function()
    {
            $("#output").append($(this).find("title").text());
            $("#output").append(": " + $(this).find("value").text() + "<br />");
    });

}
</script>
```

```
    <style type="text/css">

    #bg_mask {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 981px;
        height: 610px;
        background : url("img_dot_white.jpg") center;
        z-index: 1;
        visibility: hidden;
    } 

#baselayer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 70px 140px 175px 140px;
        padding : 30px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: red;
        visibility: visible;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z-index: 0;
    } 



    #frontlayer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0px 140px 175px 0px;
        padding : 30px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: blue;
    color: white;
        visibility: hidden;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z-index: 2;
    } 


    </style>
</head>
```

```
<div id="baselayer" onmouseover="showFrontLayer();" onmouseout="hideFrontLayer();">
    <img width="600" height="400" src="graphic.jpg" />


        <div id="bg_mask">
        <div id="frontlayer" onclick="openWin('second_page.html')" >
            <p id="output" ></p><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

I'm pulling some information from an XML file and trying to display it on a hidden layer behind an image. In IE, the second layer with text shows up, but with Opera or Chrome, only the blue background is visible. What's wrong with my code?

Edit: After trying it out with multiple browsers, I noticed only Internet Explorer has given me a prompt: 
"Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls."

I'm thinking the other browsers automatically block my XML script from running. Is there a way I can still extract my data from the XML file without running a script?

Comment: Can you provide the javascript portion of this code (showFrontLayer) and (hideFrontLayer)?

Comment: Sure, it has been added.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any JavaScript here, you can just use the CSS negation pseudo class [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to set the `visibility` of the relevant `div` to hidden when its parent is not being hovered, like so:

```css
#baselayer{
    background:red;
    border:1px solid black;
    bottom:0;
    height:400px;
    left:0;
    margin:70px 140px 175px 140px;
    padding:30px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:600px;
}
#bg_mask{
    background:url(img_dot_white.jpg) center;
    bottom:0;
    height:610px;
    left:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:981px;
}
#baselayer:not(:hover) #bg_mask{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#frontlayer{
    background:blue;
    border:1px solid black;
    bottom:0;
    color:white;
    height:400px;
    left:0;
    margin:0px 140px 175px 0px;
    padding:30px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="baselayer">
    <img width="600" height="400" src="graphic.jpg">
    <div id="bg_mask">
        <div id="frontlayer" onclick="openWin('second_page.html')">
            <p id="output"></p><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the point. Why not the other way around? Only make it visible on hover?

Comment: You can do it that way as well, if you prefer. I prefer this method as it only requires a single rule for the `visibility` rather than setting a default value and then having to overwrite it. In my book: The less code you use, the better :)

Comment: That one line of code less won't make *any* noticeable difference and - in my book -: the more thorough and [cross-browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) your code, the better.

Comment: You can see from the compatibility table at the end of the page I linked that support for `:not()` is pretty good, even IE9 recognises it. There are a few ways to achieve what's being asked here, this is one way, your answer is another.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely cut a couple lines off my code.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to be a comment, but unfortunately the space provided doesn't suffice.

```
function showFrontLayer() {
    $('#bg_mask, #frontlayer').css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function hideFrontLayer() {
    $('#bg_mask, #frontlayer').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function openWin(url) {
    window.open(url);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "info.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            parseXml(xml);
        }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("media").each(function () {
        $("#output").append($(this).find("title").first().text() + "<br />")
        .append($(this).find("description").text() + "<br />")
        .append($(this).find("keywords").text() + "<br />");
    }).find("customDataElement").each(function () {
        $("#output").append($(this).find("title").text())
        .append(": " + $(this).find("value").text() + "<br />");
    });
}
```

However, this is probably not causing your problem. You can use a simple hover in css to solve this:

```
#baselayer:hover #frontlayer {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This does exactly the same as your JS did, only in plain CSS.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/97k0akxp/